# Movable Type: Is there a way to display revision number?

Tags: movabletype

Is there any way to display how many revision has made to a entry?
I don't see this template tag in the tag reference.

I know there is `current_revision` API tag, but how do I
display this in template?

Answer (score 1):

There's no core template-level access to revision information at the moment. I don't think anyone's put together a plugin to do it yet, either.

This is entirely speculative(read: I haven't done it), but you *might* be able to extract this with the [Object plugin](https://github.com/koikikukan/mt-plugin-object), if you can figure out the templating required. That plugin is basically an MTML-based way of rummaging around the database without being restricted by what the pre-defined template tags let you do.